# Converting from spreadsheet to a lists of lists in xml

Tags: xml, xslt, openoffice-calc

I am trying to export a spreadsheet to a specific xml layout to be imported into a pdf form. I have gotten pretty far on my own but am stuck at what seems to be near the end. (Mind you, I am not very proficient with programing stuff, and my experience with XML/XSLT is limited to this project)

First, I exported an example set of data from the pdf, which gave me an idea of what I am looking for. I then imported this into Excel and got a spreadsheet from the data. This let me edit the data easily, then theoretically export it back, but...Excel wouldn't export the XML map that it created on import due to a "lists of lists" problem. This led me to putting the speadsheet into OpenOffice (technically LibreOffice) and trying an XML export filter using XSLT.

My data in the spreadsheet looks like...

```
Type    Name    Compound    Weight  Material    Weight
AAA     BBB         X           5       s         2
AAA     BBB         X           5       t         3
AAA     BBB         Y           4       r         4
```

I need it to be exported as like...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <MCD Type="AAA" Name="BBB">
  - <Product Compound="X">
     <Amount weight="5"/> 
   - <HM Material="s">
      <Amount weight="2" /> 
     </HM>
   - <HM Material="t">
      <Amount weight="3" />
     </HM>
    </Product>
  - <Product Compound="Y">
     <Amount weight="4"/> 
   - <HM Material="r">
      <Amount weight="4" /> 
     </HM>
    </Product>
   </MCD>
```

But with my current XSL, I get something more like...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <MCD Type="AAA" Name="BBB">
  - <Product Compound="X">
     <Amount weight="5"/> 
   - <HM Material="s">
      <Amount weight="2" /> 
     </HM>
    </Product>
   </MCD>
- <MCD Type="AAA" Name="BBB">
  - <Product Compound="X">
   - <HM Material="t">
      <Amount weight="3" />
     </HM>
    </Product>
   </MCD>
- <MCD Type="AAA" Name="BBB">
  - <Product Compound="Y">
     <Amount weight="4"/> 
   - <HM Material="r">
      <Amount weight="4" /> 
     </HM>
    </Product>
   </MCD>
```

My problem lies with each cell of the spreadsheet being in the output. I want to have the parent cell only be deiplayed when it changes, like in a folder tree. I hope this makes sense and someone can help me (either making it work in excel or openoffice, though from my search it seems the OpenOffice route is more likely). I have scoured for answers but nothing has quite answered my needs. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you reduce the example to something easily digestible, preferably without scrolling, say, using tables with A, B, C, 1, 2, 3 and fewer columns? Also, if you could show “I get this XML, and I would like to get this instead,” that might help, too.

Comment: Of course I can make it simpler. Sorry, I don't have too much experiance coding or asking for help. Hopefully this is nicer now. If there is anything else I can do to help you help me, just ask.

Comment: What's open office got with it? Are you searching just to transform the given CSV file to XML? Please also indicate targeted XSLT version.

Comment: I have a speadsheet in libreoffice 3.4.1 (basically the same thing as openoffice) and am using an export filter to wirte the file to XML. Right now it is saved as an ods file, though is saving as a csv makes my life easier, I am not opposed to that. To be honest, I'm not quite sure, but I think it is v1

Comment: So, what will be the input: the ods or the csv?

Comment: Curently I am using the ods as input.

Comment: Now it's a nicely posed question, I think. Are you using XSLT 1 or 2? For XSLT 1, google for “Muenchian grouping”; for XSLT 2, you'll be better off with using for-each-group. In both cases, you need to run the grouping for each level, from outer to inner.

Comment: Looking closer, I was using xslt 1 but I can use xsl 2, so I am going to try to use the for-each-group function. Thank you for the direction, from what I see, this should be able to let me do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using XSLT 2, starting from your last XML and using the following stylesheet:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="//MCD" group-by="concat(@Type,'-',@Name)">
      <MCD Type="{@Type}" Name="{@Name}">
        <xsl:for-each select="//Product[(parent::MCD/@Type = substring-before(current-grouping-key(),'-')) and (parent::MCD/@Name = substring-after(current-grouping-key(),'-'))]"> 
           <xsl:copy-of select="." />
        </xsl:for-each>
      </MCD>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

you ll get:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><MCD Type="AAA" Name="BBB"><Product Compound="X">
     <Amount weight="5"/> 
   <HM Material="s">
      <Amount weight="2"/> 
     </HM>
    </Product><Product Compound="X">
   <HM Material="t">
      <Amount weight="3"/>
     </HM>
    </Product><Product Compound="Y">
     <Amount weight="4"/> 
   <HM Material="r">
      <Amount weight="4"/> 
     </HM>
    </Product></MCD>
```